# Is it poostible to convert a python method to djagno database method?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I want to ordery my query by total value, total is forigen key to items
i use method bellow to calculte total amount .

*models.py* function

```
    def total(self):
        total=0
        for item in self.items.all():
            if item.taxed==True:
                total = total + item.amount + (item.amount*(self.tax)/(100))
            else:
                total = total + item.amount
        return total
```

my query lookslike :

```
nvoices = Invoices.objects.all().order_by()
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass a custom function to order objects. That's because `order_by()` is actually executed by the database which cannot run Python code.

But looking at your `total()` function, which in my opinion is mostly an aggregation function, I think you can actually get what you want by using a custom aggregation function which you will have to write in SQL as detailed [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#creating-your-own-aggregate-functions).

Here's an example using the standard SQL function `SUM`:

```py
from django.db.models import Sum
Invoice.objects.annotate(total=Sum('item__amount')).all().order_by('-total')
```

This should return all `Invoice` objects with an additional field `total` and ordered by that field in descending order.

You can now go ahead an replace the `Sum()` with a custom function of yours. [Here's an article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/writing-your-own-aggregation-functions/) detailing how such a function could be written.

Comment: This could possibly be done with a Case function though...

Comment: I am thinking about that as well, but I don't see how. The `CASE` statement would take in the individual item (`CASE WHEN item.taxed THEN … ELSE … END`). Therefor I think that the case statement needs to be part of the aggregation function?